# How do I get the Nuvoton infrared remote control working?

Tags: 10.10, lirc, remote-control

The ASRock ION330HT nettop computers (for use as a home theatre PC) come with a Nuvoton brand infrared remote control.  They apparently work with Ubuntu, but the .deb files on the ASRock web site are out-of-date, fail to install, and the documentation is poorly written.

http://www.asrock.com/nettop/download.asp?Model=ION%20330HT&o=Linux

Has anyone gotten these "Nuvoton rct6775/w836x7" infrared remote controls working in Ubuntu 10.10?  How did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have it working 100%. It requires building a custom kernel with Jarod Wilson's Nuvoton driver patch, see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9972151) thread.